# Parse data from table Greenplum

Tags: regex, parsing, plpgsql, greenplum

I have a table scheme2.central_id__new_numbers in Greenplum.

[image]

I need select data from scheme2.central_id__new_numbers in the form of a many-to-many relationship.

[image]

Also I write the code but must have made a wrong turn somewhere (the code doesn't work):

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_scheme.parse_new_numbers (varchar) RETURNS SETOF varchar as
    $BODY$
    declare
         i int;
    BEGIN
       FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        select 
         central_id,
         (select regexp_split_to_table((select new_numbers 
         from scheme2.central_id__new_numbers limit 1 offset i), '\s+'))
        from scheme2.central_id__new_numbers limit 1 offset i
       END LOOP;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `UNNEST()` function instead, i.e. assuming `new_numbers` column is of `int[]` data type,

```sql
SELECT central_id
, UNNEST(new_numbers) AS new_numbers 
FROM central_id__new_numbers;
```

If `new_columns` column is not an array data type then you need to use i.e. `string_to_array()` or similar before using `UNNEST()`.